# Trying to show a button only when a Wordpress custom field value is present

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

On a Wordpress site, in a product template, I have a section that shows a custom field value. On the site, the container is hidden by default. A visitor can click a button that slides open the container. The button is just in the template, static.

I am using this to show the value of my custom field:

```
if ( function_exists('get_custom_field_value') ){ 
    get_custom_field_value('fieldname', true);  
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is make it so the button only shows up if there is actually a value in the custom field.

I'm a total PHP newb. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to check if custom field is empty or not:

```
<?php

if( get_post_meta($post_id, 'fieldname', true) != '')
{
   //print your button here
}
?>
```

Comment: silent, Thank you! That didn't work exactly, but it helped me figure this out:

    <?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'nutrition_image', true) != '') { ?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button right" id="button-nutrition">see nutrition facts</a>
    <?php } ?>

Comment: of course it didn't work as is. I just help you with pseudo-code. But, I'm think you already got the point.

Comment: Your help was indispensable and is most appreciated.